# SQLite/GeoPackage over a network

Tags: qgis, geopackage, network, sqlite

In our organisation we work with data stored on an Azure network file server - pretty typical for an office. We use QGIS to read geodata files (SQLite/GeoPackage) across this network and it seems to work very well. We have sufficient performance and have not noticed any data loss/corruption in many years.

After reading the advice from [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/useovernet.html) I am however concerned that

> This simple, "remote database" approach is usually not the best way to
> use a single SQLite database from multiple systems, (even if it
> appears to "work"), as it often leads to various kinds of trouble and
> grief.

They therefore recommend a client/server database solution, although also state [here](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) that

> (with a) higher bandwidth engine-to-disk link be across the network. This works, but it is suboptimal

We connect to modest sized SQLite/GeoPackage (100MB), write only occasionally and rarely with more than one client.

I can't believe we operate this strategy in isolation and am interested to know if this is a strategy we should continue to follow.

1. Is there a recommendation from the GIS community?
2. Does QGIS do anything special to mitigate this risk?

Comment: One question per Question, please. Though if the vendor says not to do this, I think you already have your answer to the first one.

Comment: The **6.0 How to Corrupt Your Database Files** section of [File Locking And Concurrency In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) provides some specifics on the data corruption risks of using network filesystems with SQLite databases.  If you have a proper backup and recovery setup on the network filesystems, you can accept the risks and continue using the network filesystem, and simply restore the SQLite file if/when data corruption does occur.

Comment: thanks to you both for the useful tips